# Replace the mechanical switch on the electronic

Tags: mosfet, switches

I have a mechanical switch that manually switches a charged capacitor from the power supply to a load of approximately 5 ohms.
[image]

I wanted to make an electronic switch controlled by a microcontroller. I am using Power MOSFET Photovoltaic Relay PVT422. The first part of the circuit works, the capacitor is charged to 30 V, and the second forms the voltage divider "On-State Resistance + Rload", since I measured the resistance of the MOSFET in the open state = 25 ohms.

[image]

Is there any solution to this problem or a simpler one?

I had the idea to put a repeater on an op-amp in front of the load, but I would like to do without additional power supplies.

Comment: Open input state ought to be only 1uA output leakage not 25 ohms.  That is the On state with rated LED current

Comment: But Imax is only 150mA @ 1ms. So you are exceeding this . You can add current limiting R on input for <0.5s and power PFET for output. Does it need to be opto isolated?

Comment: The MOSFET is 25 ohms in the open state or in the closed state?  Neither one is good, but 25 ohms closed is maybe a factor of 20 away from what I'd expect, 25 ohms when open is wrong by a factor of several million.

Comment: 25 ohms in the open state, I measured with an ohmmeter.